# Limit of a vector direction

Tags: integration, limits, vectors, improper-integrals

I have a direction vector $\bar w$ defined by the limit over time $t$ using the following formula:

$$\bar w = \lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty}\frac{\sum_i \mathbf{x}_i r^i(t)}{\|\sum_i \mathbf{x}_i r^i(t)\|}$$

Where $\mathbf{x}_i$ are a set of constant input vectors and $r^i(t)$ are scalar functions with the limit $\forall i, \ \lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty}r^i(t) = 0$.

Another thing I know is that the limit of the integral is infinite in a sense that:
$\forall i,  \lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty}\int_0^t r^i(t')dt' = \infty$.

Is it possible to claim that:
$$\bar w = \lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty}\frac{\sum_i \mathbf{x}_i \int_0^t r^i(t')dt'}{\|\sum_i \mathbf{x}_i \int_0^t r^i(t')dt'\|}$$

Since $r^i(t)$ converges "slowly" it seems intuitive that "late-time" values will control the direction created by the integral, allowing for this equality.
However, I can't prove or disprove this.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is continouous, then we can apply LHospital's rule the following way:
$$\lim_t \frac{\int_0^t f}{t}=\lim_t \frac{f(t)}{1}=0$$
Now just multiply the fraction by $\frac{1/t}{1/t}$ and take the limit.

Comment: thanks @Botond. great solution

Comment: posted similar question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3791645/limit-of-direction-vector-integral if you can be of help there. thanks so much

Comment: Hey @Botond looking into this again. this doesn't fully add up. First, the limit is can't be directly inserted into the nominator and denominator, making this transition a bit problematic. Further, the denominator is a norm, so it's derivative is not identical to the norm of the derivative.

Comment: It seems like it's OK to write: 
$$\bar w = \lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty}\frac{\sum_i \mathbf{x}_i \int_0^t r^i(t')dt'}{ \int_0^t \|\sum_i \mathbf{x}_ir^i(t')dt'\|}$$ 
Since indeed if I take the derivative of the nominator and denominator I get the right limit with L'Hospital. But then the denominator is not exactly what I'm after, which is weird since it's a limit of a unit vector (normalized vector).
Any thoughts?