# Limit of direction vector integral

Tags: limits, vectors, improper-integrals

I have a direction vector $\bar w$ defined over time $t$ which has a **finite** limit.
Denoting, $\lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty} \bar{w}(t) = \bar{w}(\infty)$

I also have the following integral which I know the limit of is infinite:
$$\|\lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty} \int_0^t\bar{w}(t')r(t')dt'\| = \infty$$

Where $r(t)$ is a scalar function with the following limits:
$$\lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty}r(t) = 0$$.
$$\lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty}\int_0^t r(t')dt' = \infty$$.

Is it possible to claim that:
$$\lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty} \int_0^t\bar{w}(t')r(t')dt' = \bar{w}(\infty)\lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty}  \int_0^tr(t')dt'$$

Since $r(t)$ converges "slowly" it seems intuitive that "late-time" values will control the direction created by the integral, allowing for this equality.
However, I can't prove or disprove this.

Comment: Could you fix the last integral? It looks like you cane a typo in it.

Comment: Fixed the last integral

Comment: It seems like both of the integrals diverge to infinity. By the way, what does the first integral mean? $w$ is a vector, so it's integral should be a vector as well, but $\infty$ is a(n extended) real number.

Comment: Both integral go to infinity, but the question is do they both take the same "direction". since $\bar{w}$ is a direction vector, and it does converges, do the first integral converge to the direction of $\bar{w}(\infty)$?

Comment: And you're right about the mis-use of $\infty$ but the point was that the norm of the first integral is infinite. fixed that.

Comment: I have to go now, but I'll think about it. If it's a finite dimensional vector space (or a separable Hilbert space), the first thing I'd do is to pick a basis containing $w(\infty)$ as an element and see where does it lead.

Comment: Thanks @Botond! yes it is a finite dimensional vector space

Comment: I dont know your motivation but if you want to ask whether or not the limits take the same direction perhaps you should rewrite the question as $\lim_{t \xrightarrow{}\infty} \frac{\int_0^t\bar{w}(t')r(t')dt' }{\int_0^tr(t')dt'} =^{?} \bar{w}(\infty)  $